# I can't navigate to localhost in xampp server

Tags: apache, xampp

Although I'm writing the URL correctly in the browser I can't access **localhost/** or any of its directories(i.e. **localhost/directory name**) and the following message appears

> Object not found!
>   The requested URL was not found on this server. If
>   you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.6

The only thing that I can access are the virtual URLs that I have specified in the **httpd-vhosts.conf**.
When I change the port number from 80 to 8080 I can access the **[localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080)** and its directories **localhost:8080/directory name** but I can't access the virtual URLs